# How to make a progress bar in python which goes a little on as each line code is ran?

Tags: python, progress-bar

I'd like a programm that my progress bar will go on as my programm's lines goes, for example:

```
a=1
##progress=33.33%
a=2
##progress=66.66%
a=3
##progress=100%
```

So when it's 100% then my code was run completly

But my original code has a lot of lines so how would I do that in a smart way? I'd pass my current value of progress to some progress bar on some GUI but my problem is about how would I get that value not about the graphic progress bar.

I just tried to go the progress bar on by this "brute" way

Comment: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Comment: it's loop based @Konstantinos

Answer (score 0):

I found a clean solution using `rich` instead of `tqdm`:

```
def run(func, sleep=0):
    update = lambda progress, task: progress.update(task, advance=1)

    function = inspect.getsource(func)
    mylist = function.split('\n')
    mylist.remove(mylist[0])
    for num, line in enumerate(mylist):
        mylist[num] = line[8:] + "\nupdate(progress, task)\ntime.sleep(sleep)"

    myexec = ''
    for line in mylist:
         myexec += line + '\n'
    
    with Progress() as progress:
        task = progress.add_task("Working...", total=len(mylist))
        exec(myexec)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from rich.progress import Progress
    import inspect
    import time

    def myfunc():
        #chose to import these modules for progress bar example since they take a LONG time to import on my computer
        import pandas
        import openai
    
    run(myfunc)
```

This code isn't ideal, but it's the best that I could come up with. I'm not going to explain everything in this answer, but here's the breakdown:

We're using `exec()` to run code from a function, that way we can modify the function to our needs. I added some extra lines to the function to ensure that we can update the progress bar each line of the function. In the function `run()`, the argument `func` is the function, and `sleep` is the amount of time to stop the program before continuing to update the progress bar (so the progress bar isn't too fast), sleep is configurable, the default value is set to 0, and with this, we have a progress bar.

To actually run this code, I recommend saving this in a file maybe called `progress_bar`, and then you can use the function `progress_bar.run()` in your code from now on. This answer especially isn't good, since it uses `exec()`, but again, it's the best that I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your program outputs to the screen, but you also want a progress bar to show overall progress.

The [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) progress bar will let you print as you normally would while keeping the progress bar at the bottom of the terminal.

```py
import time
import enlighten

manager = enlighten.get_manager()
pbar = manager.counter(total=100, desc='Basic', unit='ticks')

for a in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulate work
    print(f'a={a}')
    pbar.update()
```

See the [documentation](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) for more [examples](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#additional-examples).